# Filling in missing rows in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, union

At first my question may seem simple and has been asked before. Bear with me - I think it is a unique question.

Table A has columns `State`, `County`, `Month`, `Year`, and `Rate`. Each State,County composite is listed several times with different dates and rate. Some rows have State and County set and everything else in that row is NULL.

Table B has default rates for each month and year. Columns are `Month`, `Year`, and `Rate`. In this table I have several years worth of default data.

So for each State,County composite in Table A I want to fill in any missing data with the data from Table B.

I created a Table C that looks just like Table A except all the data is filled in with the default data from Table B. Then I tried to UNION Table A and Table C together. But I am ending up with two problems.

First I am ending up with duplicate rows with everything the same except for the rate. In this case I want to keep only the row that was originally in Table A (not the 'default rate').

Second I am ending up with rows rows that have State and County set but everything else is NULL. I need to replace these rows with row for every single default rate.

So in the end I want to have one row for each State,County,Month,Year composite.

Is it possible to combine the tables as I have described.

Let me know if you need anything clarified. Thanks.

Table A has several thousand rows. 1 to 48 rows for each State,County composite:

```
+-------+--------+-------+------+------+
| State | County | Month | Year | Rate |
+-------+--------+-------+------+------+
| NY    | Albany | 1     | 2011 | ###  |
| NY    | Albany | 2     | 2011 | ###  |
...
| NY    | Albany | 12    | 2011 | ###  |
| NY    | Albany | 1     | 2012 | ###  |
...
| NY    | Albany | 12    | 2012 | ###  |
| NY    | Monroe | 1     | 2011 | ###  |
...
| NY    | Monroe | 12    | 2011 | ###  |
| NY    | Essex  | NULL  | NULL | NULL |
+-------+--------+-------+------+------+
```

Table B has 36 rows. One row for each month over 3 years:

```
+-------+------+------+
| Month | Year | Rate |
+-------+------+------+
| 1     | 2011 | ***  |
| 2     | 2011 | ***  |
| ...   |      |      |
| 12    | 2011 | ***  |
| 1     | 2012 | ***  |
| ...   |      |      |
| 12    | 2012 | ***  |
| 1     | 2013 | ***  |
| ...   |      |      |
| 12    | 2013 | ***  |
+-------+------+------+
```

Resulting table has more rows than Table A. Each State,County composite has at lease the 36 rows from the default table:

```
+-------+--------+-------+------+------+
| State | County | Month | Year | Rate |
+-------+--------+-------+------+------+
| NY    | Albany |     1 | 2011 | ###  |
| ...   |        |       |      |      |
| NY    | Albany |    12 | 2011 | ###  |
| NY    | Albany |     1 | 2012 | ###  |
| ...   |        |       |      |      |
| NY    | Albany |    12 | 2012 | ###  |
| NY    | Albany |     1 | 2013 | ***  |
| ...   |        |       |      |      |
| NY    | Albany |    12 | 2013 | ***  |
| NY    | Monroe |     1 | 2011 | ###  |
| ...   |        |       |      |      |
| NY    | Monroe |    12 | 2011 | ###  |
| NY    | Monroe |     1 | 2012 | ***  |
| ...   |        |       |      |      |
| NY    | Monroe |    12 | 2012 | ***  |
| NY    | Monroe |     1 | 2013 | ***  |
| ...   |        |       |      |      |
| NY    | Monroe |    12 | 2013 | ***  |
| NY    | Essex  |     1 | 2011 | ***  |
| ...   |        |       |      |      |
| NY    | Essex  |    12 | 2011 | ***  |
| NY    | Essex  |     1 | 2012 | ***  |
| ...   |        |       |      |      |
| NY    | Essex  |    12 | 2012 | ***  |
| NY    | Essex  |     1 | 2013 | ***  |
| ...   |        |       |      |      |
| NY    | Essex  |    12 | 2013 | ***  |
+-------+--------+-------+------+------+
```

Key: `***` is a rate from the default table. `###` is a rate from the other table

Comment: Can you show some sample data and queries you've tried?  Kinda hard to visualize what you're looking at.

Comment: I have added example tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best approach is to generate all combinations of the geography and time.  You can do this by taking the `state` and `county` from `tablea` and cross joining with the `year` and `month` from `tableb`.  Then use `left join` to see if there is any value in `tablea`.  If so, choose it.  Otherwise, take the value from `tableb`:

```
select sc.state, sc.county, ym.year, ym.month, coalesce(a.rate, ym.rate) as rate
from (select distinct state, county from tablea) sc cross join
     tableb ym left outer join
     tablea a
     on a.state = sc.state and a.county = sc.county and
        a.year = ym.year and a.month = ym.month ;
```

+7chars

Comment: Can you explain quickly what table sc and ym are?

Comment: Those are table aliases, abbreviations for table names that are an import part of the SQL language.

Comment: `sc` is state-county abbreviated, `ym` year-month abbreviated, the cross join takes every sc an multiples each one for every ym, so you end up with the total matrix of state-county-year-month. It is a good method for this need (sorry, your need isn't unique :).

Comment: but the last line should read "a.year = ym.year and a.month = ym.month ;" (a.month relates to YM.month)

Comment: I made the correction, sorry had to add useless characters, apparently the minimum significant edit is 6 characters. Tell that to any sql coder

Comment: @Used_By_Already . . . Your edit is correct.  The `sc.month` was a typo.  Thank you for fixing it.